# Box2d , How do i identify different object class from body.getUserData

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I have 2 Classes of game objects

```
Player and Enemy,
```

And 2 Body objects ,

```
bodyPlayer and bodyEnemy
```

Then, i set

```
bodyPlayer.setUserData(new Player);
bodyPlayer.setUserData(new Enemy);
```

When i getUserData from both bodies. 
How do i identify which is class of object from the userData.

Or any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use strings instead Player or Enemy.

```
bodyPlayer.setUserData("Player");
bodyPlayer.setUserData("Enemy");
```

And next to compare:

```
bodyPlayer.getUserData().equals("Player")
```

I am not sure but when you want to use objects like Player or Enemy you should use instanceof:

```
bodyPlayer.getUserData() instanceof Player
```